# Text color for link is not black

Tags: css, hyperlink

Could someone help me edit this fiddle. How can I get the text black? The CSS coding says black but it appears light grey in the dreamweaver preview screen.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/raphaelr/8AffQ/)

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div id="class">
    <p><a href="calendar.html">Calendar</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: It is black in the fiddle !!

Comment: Does it look correct in an actual browser?  The preview screen may be inaccurate.

Comment: When you click run in the fiddle it changes color.

Answer (score 4):

Your link color is black, just add this CSS.

```
a:hover,a:visited { color:#000; }
```

You do not see black link because you have already clicked the on link, so the browser will apply visited styling by default. So somewhere you need to override these CSS style declarations

**Example**

```
a:link    {color:#000;}  /* unvisited link  */
a:visited {color:#000;}  /* visited link    */
a:hover   {color:#000;}  /* mouse over link */
a:active  {color:#000;}  /* selected link   */
```

Answer (score 3):

**used to this**

```
#class a{
color:#000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the dreamweaver you using is not compatible for good colors. It is just for sketching.
Believe colors in browsers.

```
#class a:hover {
    font-family: "Brush Script MT";
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #00C; <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#class a:active {
    font-family: "Brush Script MT";
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #00C; <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

change the color codes!!! into #000

Comment: You don't have to repeat all of the unchanged properties for `:hover` and `:active`.

Comment: @Blender that is not true. If you try to click and drag a link, the `:hover` styling will disappear but the `:active` styling will remain (in Safari and Chrome)

Comment: @henryaaron: I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: @Blender In Safari or Chrome, click and hold a link to my or your username and drag your mouse away. The underline will disappear, because the underline is only applied to `:hover`. If the underline was applied to `a:hover,a:active` than the underline would remain when you click and drag a link.

Comment: @henryaaron: What I'm saying is that you don't have to set `font-size` and `font-family` if the values don't change.

Answer (score 1):

or most basic:

```
<a href="calendar.html"><font color="black">Calendar</font></a>
```

link - color - text - /color - /link

Comment: The [`<font>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/font) was deprecated in HTML4 and is obsolete in HTML5. Don't use it.

Comment: The color attribute as well, for that matter. @Blender

Answer (score 0):

It is already black, No need to add additional CSS or stuff. Some configuration problem in your dreamweaver preview screen.